# SpamAssassin: custom rules and score

Tags: spf, dkim, spamassassin

For my mailserver, i want do add some custom rules and scores for spamasassin DKIM and SPF checks.

Currently i use following custom settings:

```
score   DKIM_SIGNED 0
score   DKIM_VALID  -1
score   SPF_NONE    1
score   SPF_PASS    -1
```

Problem:

there exists a tag if a mail has no spf, but no setting if a mail is not dkim signed.
how can i use or implement

```
score   DKIM_UNSIGNED   1
```

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: You will probs get an answer much quicker by posting on the [mailing list](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/MailingLists#MailingLists-Users)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like this:

```perl
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::DKIM
score DKIM_SIGNED    -0.01
meta  DKIM_UNSIGNED  !DKIM_SIGNED
score DKIM_UNSIGNED  1
endif
```

(Assigning a zero score to a rule disables its evaluation, so `!DKIM_SIGNED` would always be true. The solution is to give it a trivial score. It also uses a conditional to ensure the plugin is loaded, as otherwise `!DKIM_SIGNED` would again always be true.)

⚠ However, **I recommend neither that nor tinkering with DKIM/SPF weights.**

*Lots* of spammers and dirty marketers implement SPF and DKIM. Then there's all of the attacks that come in through freemail providers like GMail, Yahoo, Hotmail/Outlook, etc. Those infrastructures *all* have proper DKIM and SPF signing. You'd be giving all of them a big ham weight (-2), making it that much harder for SpamAssassin to convict them.

Similarly, lots of legitimate mails fail to use (or correctly implement) either SPF or DKIM.

You can look this up and see: Consider the public SpamAssassin Rule QA logs for 2022-01-12. Since these don't run the DKIM plugin on all tests, let's look at [__DKIM_EXISTS](https://ruleqa.spamassassin.org/20220112-r1896943-n/__DKIM_EXISTS/detail) (there is a DKIM signature header) instead of DKIM_SIGNED (there is a properly-formatted DKIM signature header) or DKIM_VALID (it matches). __DKIM_EXISTS is nearly identical to DKIM_SIGNED.

22.5% of spam and 71.4% of ham have DKIM, meaning 87.5% of spam and 38.6% of ham lack it.

Do you *really* want to remove 2 points from a ~quarter of your spam and add 1 point to a ~third of your ham?

---

Instead, I'd recommend explicitly blessing known-safe domains:

```perl
whitelist_from_dkim *@safe.example.com *@serverfault.com
whitelist_from_spf  *@safe.example.com *@serverfault.com
```

This allows valid DKIM-signed and SPF-authorized mail from just the listed domains. You can also use `def_whitelist_from_dkim` and `def_whitelist_from_spf` for lighter ham weights.

You could also consider doing this automatically via [TxRep](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/TxRep), but only after making sure you're properly using IP [DNSBLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System-based_Blackhole_List) (see [DnsBlocklists](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/DnsBlocklists)). I'd say DNSBLs and Bayesian content inspection are the two best weapons to combat spam overall.

Comment: Excellent answer! Only a DMARC policy can tell whether an unsigned message is a problem or not. Additionally, failed SPF or DMARC checks can also be used for *connection-stage rejection*.

Comment: I just added efficacy data to my answer which reinforces Esa's and my "don't do this" sentiment. I _very_ strongly advise against SMTP actions for SPF. Just DMARC, and even that has some doubt from more conservative admins given the misconfigurations out there.